# How to get the sub-string from a string and store it in an array using power-shell script?

Tags: android, powershell

How can I extract a substring using PowerShell?

I have imported data from a text file and split on the basis of the new line the data contains the string in the format of *package:com.google.android.ext.services*

I have this kind of strings which is stored in one array

*package:com.google.android.ext.services*

I want this string to be stored in a new array

*com.google.android.ext.services*

```
$file_app_package = Get-Content C:\Users\sharmkus\Desktop\Data.txt
$application_package = $file_app_package.split([Environment]::NewLine)
$startIndex = 0
$Application_Package 
$substring = ''

foreach($app_package in $application_package)
{
    $startIndex = $app_package.IndexOf(":")+1

     $substring = $app_package.Substring($startIndex)
     $Application_Package += $substring
} 

foreach($lst in $Application_Package)
{
    echo $lst
}
```

The output that I am getting after running is:
*package:com.google.android.ext.services*
followed by
*com.google.android.ext.services*

I'll share the whole output below

```
package:com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.google.android.ext.services
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.google.android.ext.shared
package:com.android.protips
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.mms.service
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.google.android.apps.messaging
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.android.providers.downloads.ui
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.android.carrierconfig
package:android
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.camera2
package:com.android.egg
package:com.android.mtp
package:com.android.launcher3
package:com.android.backupconfirm
package:com.google.android.deskclock
package:com.android.statementservice
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.google.android.apps.tachyon
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:com.google.android.music
package:com.android.printspooler
package:com.android.dreams.basic
package:com.android.inputdevices
package:com.android.sdksetup
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
package:com.google.android.webview
package:com.android.server.telecom
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
package:com.android.keychain
package:com.android.chrome
package:com.android.dialer
package:com.android.gallery3d
package:com.google.android.packageinstaller
package:com.android.emulator.smoketests
package:com.google.android.gms
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.google.android.videos
package:com.android.proxyhandler
package:com.android.fallback
package:com.android.inputmethod.latin
package:org.chromium.webview_shell
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.printservice.recommendation
package:com.google.android.apps.photos
package:com.google.android.calendar
package:com.android.managedprovisioning
package:com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
package:com.google.android.gsf.login
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.android.netspeed
package:com.google.android.backuptransport
package:jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
package:com.android.bookmarkprovider
package:com.android.settings
package:com.android.calculator2
package:com.android.cts.ctsshim
package:com.android.vpndialogs
package:com.google.android.talk
package:com.android.phone
package:com.android.shell
package:com.android.wallpaperbackup
package:com.android.providers.blockednumber
package:com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:com.android.emergency
package:com.android.location.fused
package:com.android.systemui
package:com.android.customlocale2
package:com.google.android.play.games
package:com.android.development
package:com.android.providers.contacts
package:com.android.captiveportallogin
package:com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.google.android.ext.services
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.google.android.ext.shared
package:com.android.protips
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.mms.service
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.google.android.apps.messaging
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.android.providers.downloads.ui
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.android.carrierconfig
package:android
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.camera2
package:com.android.egg
package:com.android.mtp
package:com.android.launcher3
package:com.android.backupconfirm
package:com.google.android.deskclock
package:com.android.statementservice
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.google.android.apps.tachyon
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:com.google.android.music
package:com.android.printspooler
package:com.android.dreams.basic
package:com.android.inputdevices
package:com.android.sdksetup
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
package:com.google.android.webview
package:com.android.server.telecom
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
package:com.android.keychain
package:com.android.chrome
package:com.android.dialer
package:com.android.gallery3d
package:com.google.android.packageinstaller
package:com.android.emulator.smoketests
package:com.google.android.gms
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.google.android.videos
package:com.android.proxyhandler
package:com.android.fallback
package:com.android.inputmethod.latin
package:org.chromium.webview_shell
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.printservice.recommendation
package:com.google.android.apps.photos
package:com.google.android.calendar
package:com.android.managedprovisioning
package:com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
package:com.google.android.gsf.login
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.android.netspeed
package:com.google.android.backuptransport
package:jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
package:com.android.bookmarkprovider
package:com.android.settings
package:com.android.calculator2
package:com.android.cts.ctsshim
package:com.android.vpndialogs
package:com.google.android.talk
package:com.android.phone
package:com.android.shell
package:com.android.wallpaperbackup
package:com.android.providers.blockednumber
package:com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:com.android.emergency
package:com.android.location.fused
package:com.android.systemui
package:com.android.customlocale2
package:com.google.android.play.games
package:com.android.development
package:com.android.providers.contacts
package:com.android.captiveportallogin
com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
com.google.android.youtube
com.google.android.ext.services
com.android.providers.telephony
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
com.android.providers.calendar
com.android.providers.media
com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
com.google.android.ext.shared
com.android.protips
com.android.documentsui
com.android.externalstorage
com.android.htmlviewer
com.android.mms.service
com.android.providers.downloads
com.google.android.apps.messaging
com.google.android.configupdater
com.android.defcontainer
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.vending
com.android.pacprocessor
com.android.certinstaller
com.android.carrierconfig
android
com.android.contacts
com.android.camera2
com.android.egg
com.android.mtp
com.android.launcher3
com.android.backupconfirm
com.google.android.deskclock
com.android.statementservice
com.google.android.gm
com.google.android.apps.tachyon
com.google.android.setupwizard
com.android.providers.settings
com.android.sharedstoragebackup
com.google.android.music
com.android.printspooler
com.android.dreams.basic
com.android.inputdevices
com.android.sdksetup
com.google.android.apps.docs
com.google.android.apps.maps
com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
com.google.android.webview
com.android.server.telecom
com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
com.android.keychain
com.android.chrome
com.android.dialer
com.android.gallery3d
com.google.android.packageinstaller
com.android.emulator.smoketests
com.google.android.gms
com.google.android.gsf
com.google.android.tts
com.google.android.partnersetup
com.google.android.videos
com.android.proxyhandler
com.android.fallback
com.android.inputmethod.latin
org.chromium.webview_shell
com.google.android.feedback
com.google.android.printservice.recommendation
com.google.android.apps.photos
com.google.android.calendar
com.android.managedprovisioning
com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
com.google.android.gsf.login
com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
com.android.netspeed
com.google.android.backuptransport
jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
com.android.bookmarkprovider
com.android.settings
com.android.calculator2
com.android.cts.ctsshim
com.android.vpndialogs
com.google.android.talk
com.android.phone
com.android.shell
com.android.wallpaperbackup
com.android.providers.blockednumber
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.android.emergency
com.android.location.fused
com.android.systemui
com.android.customlocale2
com.google.android.play.games
com.android.development
com.android.providers.contacts
com.android.captiveportallogin
```

Comment: if all you want is the part after the `:`, then this is one way to get it >> ~('package:com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim' -split ':')[1]`. the output from that  = `com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim`

Comment: You are adding the substrings to an array that already contains the whole original text lines. Define a new array to store the results in. Something like `$apps=@()`. P.s. `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch already returns an array. No need to split that on newlines.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do the job. [*grin*] it replaces the `package:` at the start of each array item with nothing, sends it to the collection $Var, and then shows the content of the $Var.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
package:com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.google.android.ext.services
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.google.android.ext.shared
package:com.android.protips
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.mms.service
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.google.android.apps.messaging
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.android.providers.downloads.ui
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.android.carrierconfig
package:android
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.camera2
package:com.android.egg
package:com.android.mtp
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$DePackagedInStuff = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $IS_Item -replace 'package:', ''
    }

$DePackagedInStuff
```

output ...

```
com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
com.google.android.youtube
com.google.android.ext.services
com.android.providers.telephony
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
com.android.providers.calendar
com.android.providers.media
com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
com.google.android.ext.shared
com.android.protips
com.android.documentsui
com.android.externalstorage
com.android.htmlviewer
com.android.mms.service
com.android.providers.downloads
com.google.android.apps.messaging
com.google.android.configupdater
com.android.defcontainer
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.vending
com.android.pacprocessor
com.android.certinstaller
com.android.carrierconfig
android
com.android.contacts
com.android.camera2
com.android.egg
com.android.mtp
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Can I ask you what was wrong in my code, I know its funny but I recently started programming and also wanted to know what is the best way to learn Powershell scripting, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kushagra - i think that Theo pointed it out correctly - you are adding the substring BACK INTO the source collection. [*grin*] this line `$Application_Package += $substring` is doing a major no-no - modifying a collection while looping thru the collection. that should only be done if you absolutely must do it ... and even then it is likely a bad idea. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly simplified version as you mentioned that you are new to Powershell:

```
$InStuff = @'
package:com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.google.android.ext.services
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
package:com.google.android.ext.shared
package:com.android.protips
package:com.android.documentsui
package:com.android.externalstorage
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.mms.service
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.google.android.apps.messaging
package:com.google.android.configupdater
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.android.providers.downloads.ui
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.pacprocessor
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.android.carrierconfig
package:android
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.camera2
package:com.android.egg
package:com.android.mtp
'@

$file_app_package = $InStuff -Split [Environment]::NewLine
$Application_Package = @()

$file_app_package | ForEach-Object {
    $Application_Package += $_ -Split ':' | Select-Object -Last 1
}

$Application_Package | ForEach-Object {
    $_
}
```